# Варианты подключения резервного канала

Tags: сеть

Добрый день. Ситуация такая, есть маршрутизатор zyxell на 2-м этаже,к нему подключена выделенка, есть адсл-роутер на 5-м этаже, к нему подключен адсл интернет. 2-й и 5-й этажи связанны одним кабелем. Со 2-го от маршрутизатора на 5-й идет интернет, соответственно 2-й и 5-й объединены в одну сеть. Необходимо: с 5-го от адсл-роутера передавать на 2-й в маршрутизатор интернет ( необходимость в резервном канале). Вопрос: как лучше сделать передачу интернета с 5-го на 2-й, непрокидывая еще один кабель между этажами? Спасибо

Comment: Я вот ни фига не понял, со второго на пятый, с пятого на второй. Чуть конкретнее и не связывать этаж и роутер - это разные вещи. Проще нужно быть. На какой этаже, что находится тут вообще роли играть не должно.Опишите понятнее.> есть 2 роутера.. на одном инет есть. нужно чтобы и на втором было.

Comment: указать второй шлюзом для первого

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно 1. указать **два** шлюза компам (+ отстроить распределение нагрузки)2. в случае падения и-нета на 2-ом - оперативненько поменять всем шлюз на тот, что на 5-ом (придёццо побегать)3. (на мой взгляд - оптимально) ткнуть в разрез старенькую машинку с тремя сетевушками для работы маршрутизатором. 1 - смотрит на zyxel, 2 - смотрит на 5-ый этаж (по 4-ём жилам), 3 - смотрит внутрь сети. На машинке софтиной (у мну стоит KerioWF) настраивается доступ в и-нет по двум каналам (распределение нагрузки ИЛИ резерв при падении). Связь между 2 и 5 - по 4-ём оставшимся жилам.4. давать 2-ому инет отдельно, 5-ому - отдельно, кабель использовать как связь между этажами.

Answer (score 0):

может заменить на 2 этаже маршрутизатор на новый с 2 wan?

Comment: к сожалению не получится, покупать начальство ничего не хочет. Опишу еще раз, а то действительно не особо понятно. Есть система: выделенка -wan1_zyxell-lan (2 этаж) - lan через свич ( 5 этаж). адсл роутер (5 этаж). Необходимо сделать адсл роутер - свич (5 этаж) - lan (2 этаж) - wan2_zyxell. Этажи указываю для того, чтобы было понятно, что кабель бросить еще один не получится, вай-фай не добивает ( толстые стены и т.д.).

Comment: Не знаю как сделать по настройкам то, что ты хочешь... но если у тебя есть вариант кинуть кабель, но кабель кидать нельзя) для инета нужно 4 жилки, подели какой-то кабель на 2 кабеля, обожми правильно и должно работать.